# How to increment string value in Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, while-loop

How to increment strings in Python?

I have the following string: `str = 'tt0000002'`
and I want to increase this string to `'tt0000003', 'tt0000004','tt0000005' (...) to 'tt0010000'` using a loop.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

You could directly generate the ids:

example here with values between 2 and 100 with increments of 10:

```py
ids = [f'tt{i:07d}' for i in range(2, 100, 10)]
```

output:

```
['tt0000002',
 'tt0000012',
 'tt0000022',
 'tt0000032',
 'tt0000042',
 'tt0000052',
 'tt0000062',
 'tt0000072',
 'tt0000082',
 'tt0000092']
```

If you really need to increment from your string:

```py
def increment(s):
    # splitting here after 2 characters, but this could use a regex
    # or any other method if the identifier is more complex
    return f'{s[:2]}{int(s[2:])+1:07d}'
```

example:

```
>>> mystr = 'tt0000002'
>>> increment(mystr)
'tt0000003'
```

##### edit

here is a "smarter" version that should work with any id of the form 'XXX0000':

```py
def increment(s):
    import re
    try:
        a, b = re.match('(\D*)(\d+)', s).groups()
    except (AttributeError, IndexError):
        print('invalid id')
        return 
    return f'{a}{int(b)+1:0{len(b)}d}'
```

examples:

```
>>> increment('tt0000002')
'tt0000003'
>>> increment('abc1')
'abc2'
>>> increment('abc999')
'abc1000'
>>> increment('0000001')
'0000002'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ugly code but works

s='tt0000002'

for k in range(100): #increase the range 
    print(s)
    n=int(s[2:])
    n_s=str(n+1)
    l=len(n_s)

    temp='tt'
    for z in range(0,7-l):
        temp+='0'
        s=temp+n_s
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One not so elegant way will be:

```
def increment_string(string, num_chars, numbers):
    return [f'{string}{str(0) * (num_chars-len(str(i)))}' + str(i) for i in numbers]
        
increment_string(string = 'tt', num_chars = 8, numbers = [1,10,50,100,1000,100000,1000000,1000000,10000000])
```